# Estimate data transmission rate on a given frequency using FM

Tags: rf, frequency-modulation

How can I estimate how much data can I transmit on a given radio frequency range using FM?

My goal is to consider using radio to transmit data packages, and I want to evaluate bandwidth.

Plus points for the question: how much of a problem will distance be? We are looking for something like 100km on an open field.

Comment: Using how much bandwidth per channel?

Comment: Depends on dBmV or mW power with BW and BER  < I would use 5:1 deviation ratio so Bit rate is 20% of deviation for low level.   But you can obviously use Shannon's Law to increase that with SNR and QAM/QPSK compression   with more power. Learn to use Friis Law which works for line of site. Just got my 343 Mbps Surfboard Modem Damn fast but  not  working yet. Only bought 70 MBps $40/mo today no contract Rogers

Comment: Also note that when we say "FM", we typically mean the *analogue* modulation; that's not very useful for transporting data in packets. Why did you define the modulation before designing the rest of the system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frequency and the use of FM actually have little to do with it. Although at 100 km range, the propagation characteristics of different frequencies will come into play.

The key parameters are SNR (signal-to-noise ratio) and bandwidth (BW).

The [Shannon-Hartley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%E2%80%93Hartley_theorem) equation for channel capacity (C) tells us:

$$C = \text{BW}(1 + \log_2 \text{SNR})$$

For maximum robustness against fading (poor SNR), it is normal to pick a modulation scheme that requires about 1 Hz per bits/second. But high-bandwidth applications such as digital TV use more complex schemes that might transmit as much as 6 bps/Hz.

However, for the distance you're talking about, you're going to need power levels that will require a license to use. This means that you're going to have to figure out what kind of license you'll need in your country, and this will dictate things like the frequencies and bandwidth available to you.

If this is for non-commercial purposes, it's possible that an [amateur radio](https://ham.stackexchange.com/) license would be appropriate.